# Problema ao compilar: no input files compilation terminated

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

Estou começando a programar em C, mas ai para usar o GCC ta me dando o seguinte problema quando uso o cmd:

> gcc.exe: fatal error: no imput files  compilation terminated

Gostaria de saber o que fazer, pois tudo que encontrei foi só sobre instalar e adicionar o diretório no PATH. Mesmo refazendo e revendo cada detalhe, ainda não consigo fazer nada. Talvez seja eu mesmo que não saiba o que estou fazendo xD.

Comment: Qual comando você está fazendo no cmd que retorna este erro?

Comment: Passe o arquivo a ser compilado.

Comment: Jéferson, to usando o comando C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe, pq todo lugar que vi fala pra conferir usando isso...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se este erro ocorreu após você digitar o comando `gcc` no `cmd` a sua instalação está correta. Mas é preciso completar a sintaxe para que o `gcc` funcione passando o nome do arquivo a ser compilado e a saída.

```
gcc seuArquivo.c -o nomeDoExecutavel
```

E para executar chame o seu executável:

```
nomeDoExecutavel
```